# Tool to convert python to c#

Tags: c#, python

Is there any tool or way in which I can convert or translate python code to c# code?

Comment: Any such tool would probably emit _terrible_ C# code, if it would even work at all.  You'd be _much_ better off actually learning what the code is doing and writing it in C#.

Comment: Found a useful converter which converted some complex python code to C# - https://www.javainuse.com/py2csharp

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hm, wouldn't it be wiser to reuse the existing Python code base via [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/), for example?

Comment: is iron python a software to run the python code? or, something else?

Comment: Yes, basically it is, have a look at the project homepage. It is easy to write python code which uses .NET types and is executed in the CLR. The other way round is not that easy, but possible... It depends on the complexity of the python code you've got whether this is a way to go or if a simple rewrite will do.

Comment: @explorer, See my blog post on IronPython here: http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/10/04/using-dynamic-in-the-real-world-with-ironpython/

Comment: Sometimes, it make sense to actually look at converted code. Just being able to run Python via the CLR is not always the appropriate solution. Yes, sometimes a rough cut conversion is all you need--or is at least appropriate as s starting point.

Answer (score 16):

There is an opensource tool that may be useful for conversion of Python to C#:

https://github.com/uxmal/pytocs

the sample conversions in that page look promising