# Convert pythonecode into c#

Tags: c#, python, .net

I have to integrate to some device that needs to generate some `id` 
this device has no `SDK` or `API` but, I have found some project in `python` that works fine.

for now, iv tested the option to run the `python` script as a process
but it's not good option.

**Code :**

```py
TRANSID_PREFIX = 'web'
def genTransId(self, trans_type=TRANSID_PREFIX):
        def float2hex(f):
            MAXHEXADECIMALS = 15
            w = f // 1
            d = f % 1

            # Do the whole:
            if w == 0: result = '0'
            else: result = ''
            while w:
                w, r = divmod(w, 16)
                r = int(r)
                if r > 9: r = chr(r+55)
                else: r = str(r)
                result =  r + result

            # And now the part:
            if d == 0: return result

            result += '.'
            count = 0
            while d:
                d = d * 16
                w, d = divmod(d, 1)
                w = int(w)
                if w > 9: w = chr(w+55)
                else: w = str(w)
                result +=  w
                count += 1
                if count > MAXHEXADECIMALS: break

            return result

        now = datetime.today()
        return trans_type+"!" + float2hex(random.random() * math.pow(2, 32)).lower() + "!" + str(int((time.mktime(now.timetuple())*1e3 + now.microsecond/1e3)))
```

Comment: The Python code is mainly just doing some math—so it seems like it would be relatively easy to convert to C#. You don't say why you think running the script as a process is "not good option", but if nothing else, I think doing would be overkill for something as trivial what this code is doing (as well as relatively slow).

Answer (score 1):

[Tool to convert python to c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11373742/tool-to-convert-python-to-c-sharp)
and 
https://github.com/uxmal/pytocs

But, can you give some more info on your statement:
"iv tested the option to run the python script as a process but it's not good option" ?

Comment: and it's not a good option because it will be on a computer that doesn't use python